# Finding the number of columns a table has

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

How can I find out the number of columns a table has?

I use oracle 10g and I want to develop a J2EE application to count the number of columns of different tables.

Comment: You either query a database catalog view or access the `DatabaseMetaData` object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's what the system catalogs are for:

```
select count(*)
from all_tab_columns
where owner = 'SOME_USER'
  and table_name = 'SOME_TABLE';
```

To get it per table, use a `group by

```
select table_name, count(*)
from all_tab_columns
where owner = 'SOME_USER'
group by table_name
order by table_name;
```

More details about the system catalogs can be found in the manual:

- [ALL_TAB_COLUMNS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2094.htm#I1020277)
- [Data Dictionary Views](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_part.htm#i125539)

Answer (score 3):

You can query this system table:

```
SELECT table_name, count(*)
FROM user_tab_columns 
WHERE table_name = '...';
```

Add a `GROUP BY` if you need to query more than one table:

```
SELECT table_name, count(*)
FROM user_tab_columns 
WHERE table_name IN ('...', '...')
GROUP BY table_name;
```